# Which is more basic among N-ethylpiperidin and 1-azabicyclooctane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

Shouldn't A be more basic than A because in B the conjugate base formed in B is more unstable as compared to A and because a bridge head nitrogen is formed In B which is comparatively unstable than conjugate base formed in A?

[image]

Comment: According to me you can see stability , but how how are you comparing the stabilities, there is not much difference in stabilities of conjugate bases!

Answer (score 1):

The basic nature of amines is mostly dependent on their ability to donate their lone pair rather than stability of the conjugate acid formed.

B, due to steric hindrance, does not undergo [Amine Inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_inversion). The lone pair is thus stationary and more prone to donation. Hence, B is more basic than A.